# Visibilitychange cannot be monitored after jumping to a new page in the Vue，How to slove it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The questions mentioned before have been closed. Recently I finally found the reason why `Visibilitychange` could not monitor.I hope this problem can be solved this time.

On the initial page, `visibilitychange` can monitor page changes normally, but on the new page, No matter how you switch pages, the event cannot be triggered, and document.hidden is always false.I operate on the computer.

I add `visibilitychange` to the page or `main.js`

```js
 document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
        console.log('vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv')
 });
```

I jumped to the new page like this

```js
 let p = {path: '/test',query:{mode: 1}}
 let routeData = this.$router.resolve(p);
 window.open(routeData.href, '_blank');
```

Note: It is a different tab page in the same browser window

What can I do to make `visibilitychange` listen for new pages?

update:

I use this code in `Chrome version  84.0.4147.89`, and the `visibilitychange` cannot be triggered after jumping to a new page

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="window.open(location.href,'_blank')">go</button>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
            console.log('vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv')
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add visibilitychange to the other pages?

Comment: They belong to the same vue project, and I added the visibilitychange event to both the new page and main.js ,The result will not be triggered when used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.Someone finally answered my question on another Q&A platform.
Answer from Acurse on Zhihu.I use Google Translate to translate the answer

Unfortunately, I have also noticed this problem. Since a performance optimization strategy I am doing recently is closely related to this API, I checked the changelog of chrome for the first time and did not find relevant content in v84 and v83. Recently on stackoverflow There are one or two of the same question, but it was either unanswered or closed. In short, it may be because there are too few people using it and no useful discussion and reference are found. After some sorting out, I finally locate the window features. I think this may be an adjustment of chrome's security policy (but the changelog is not mentioned, and the scope of influence is unknown), and the solution is also very simple.

```js
    // link
    window.open('xxx','_blank')
    // or
    <a href="xxx"></a> to // link
    window.open('xxx','_blank','noopener')
    // or
    <a href="xxx" rel="noopener"></a>
```

The problem is resolved.

Author: Acurse
Link: https://www.zhihu.com/question/407426561/answer/1358481753
Source: Zhihu
The copyright belongs to the author. For commercial reprints, please contact the author for authorization. For non-commercial reprints, please indicate the source.

Answer (score 0):

If the new page contain `main.js`,then its `visibilitychange` event will trigger in the new window's `vm`,you can check your new windows console to find the log.

Comment: There is no log on the new page, whether it is switching tabs or switching tabs after refreshing, it cannot be triggered. If you set a timer to print `document.hidden` all the time, its value is always false. I suspect this is a chrome bug, I will try to write a demo

Comment: I am using chrome84 version